# Why is the base DC for a spell saving throw 8?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, game-design, difficulty-class, designer-reasons

Does anyone know what was the rationale behind making the base DC of a spell saving throw 8 instead of 10 in D&D 5e? Most attacks, passive attributes, spell attacks use 10 as the base. The average of a d20 die roll is 10.5 (rounded down would be 10).

8 seems like a very specific choice and slightly arbitary.

This information is not included in the PHB, DMG or anything as far as I can tell. Have the designers talked about it anywhere?

---

♦ Mod note: Since this question is asking for the reasons designers made a particular choice, answers are expected to provide actual evidence that a given reason is what was employed by the designers. That evidence is gonna have to be statements or commentary of some form from someone who was a designer at the time (or can similarly speak to it). **Answers which purely propose a guess or estimate based on pattern matching will be removed.** (Several such answers have already been.)

This question is distinct from "what is the effect of the base DC being 8?". If anyone has legitimate interest in asking that, and can fully form it as a stack question, they should do so as a new question.

Comment: @Wyrmwood The rewrite of this question appeared inappropriate as it seemed to invalidate an answer and was not done by the original querrant. As a result, I rolled back.

Comment: While I don't think invalidating the answer is an issue here (removed as speculation), the edit feels like a bit too heavy a rework and not truly necessary. This question seems to me as clearly asking for and needing the actual designer reason (ie. needs source for).

Comment: On the off chance MooseBoost returns, are there any particular concerns or reasons for asking for this, other than academic curiosity? Are there any potential changes or effects you're worried about? (This may or may not make a difference to what answers are appropriate for the question)

Comment: The "opinion based" close reason states: "This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations." The six deleted unsupported answers has determined this to be true, so I am voting to close.